# Getting sample data from NAudio WasapiLoopbackCapture

Tags: c#, naudio

I am using WasapiLoopbackCapture from the NAudio C# library to capture audio being sent to my computer speakers. My goal is to get the samples and send them to an FFT function to get the spectrum data.

I'm trying to find out how exactly to parse the incoming audio data, but it seems that the answer to my question is split up and scattered around several blog posts and Stack Overflow answers, so I would like to get a definitive answer for my situation.

My waveIn.WaveFormat says I have 32 bits/sample and 2 channels. It also says that the encoding is `IeeeFloat`.

From what I've gathered, left and right channel samples are interleaved (left, right, left, right, etc.) and if there are 4 bytes/sample, every 4 bytes in the buffer makes up a sample (this is probably obvious to most, but I want to verify). Also, is the data little endian? and will the `BitConverter.ToSingle()` function take care of that?

This is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IWaveIn waveIn = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
    waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;
    waveIn.StartRecording();
}

static void waveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < e.BytesRecorded; i += 8)
    {
        float leftSample = BitConverter.ToSingle(e.Buffer, i);
        float rightSample = BitConverter.ToSingle(e.Buffer, i + 4);
    }
}
```

Does this recover the samples correctly?

Comment: looks good to me, are you having any problems with the samples?

Comment: No, not having any problems. But I'm not sure what to look for. Just wanted to be certain that I was doing it correctly. So, from here, I can pass these floats into an FFT function and get spectrum data?

Comment: yes sure, but remember that you might not get an exact power of 2 number of samples, so you may need to do some additional buffering

Comment: Right. I add these samples to a buffer, and once the size if that buffer reaches 2048, I pass it to FFT.

Comment: yeah, one of the NAudio demos has a class called `SampleAggregator` which does that

Comment: Okay. I'll check that out. Thanks Mark!